# Counting which numbers fall in a certain bracket

Tags: python, interval

I'm taking a text file that looks like this:

> ```
> 77, 66, 80, 81
> 40,  5, 35, -1
> 51, 58, 62, 34
>  0, -1, 21, 18
> 61, 69, 58, 49
> 81, 82, 90, 76
> 44, 51, 60, -1
> 64, 63, 60, 66
> -1, 38, 41, 50
> 69, 80, 72, 75
> ```

and I'm counting which numbers fall in a certain bracket:

```
f = open("//path to file", "r")
text = f.read()
split = text.split()

greater70=0
sixtys=0
fiftys=0
fortys=0
nomarks=0

for word in split:
    temp = word.replace(',', '')
    number = int(temp)
    if number > 70:
        greater70+=1
    if number >= 60 and number <= 69:
        sixtys+=1    
    if number >= 50 and number <= 59:
        fiftys+=1
    if number >= 40 and number <= 49:
        fortys+=1 
    if number == -1:
        nomarks+=1           

print greater70 
print sixtys
print fiftys
print fortys
print nomarks
```

Have I done it in an efficient way sensible way or do experienced Python users think it looks a little convoluted?

Comment: Is 70 meant to be ignored or is that a mistake?

Comment: I'd be tempted to divide by 10 and use counter.

Answer (score 4):

Notes:

- Creating so many variables is a warning sign that they should be grouped  somehow (an object, a dictionary, ...). I'd use a dictionary here.
- Consider learning some [functional programming](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html) (as opposed to imperative programming) to apply it when it improves the code (IMO: most of the time). Here it means basically using [collections.counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [generator expressions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).
- Don't read whole files, read them line by line: `for line in file_descriptor`.
- There are programmatic ways of detecting intervals of numbers (simple loop, binary search). However, since you have here only 5 intervals it's probably fine just to write a conditional as you did. If you had, let's say 20 intervals, a conditional branch would be a very sad thing to see.
- Conditional branches are more clear when you use non-overlapping conditions with `if`/`elif`/`else` (effectively working as expressions instead of statements).

I'd write:

```
from collections import Counter

def get_interval(x):
    if x > 70:
        return "greater70"
    elif 60 <= x < 70:
        return "sixtys"    
    elif x >= 50:
        return "fiftys"
    elif x >= 40:
        return "fortys" 
    elif x == -1:
        return "nomarks"   

with open("inputfile.txt") as file:
    counter = Counter(get_interval(int(n)) for line in file for n in line.split(","))
# Counter({'sixtys': 10, 'greater70': 10, None: 7, ..., 'fortys': 4})
```

Comment: Aren't those `for` clauses the wrong way around?  I.e. shouldn't it be `Counter(get_interval(int(n)) for n in line.split(",") for line in file)`?

Comment: @user9876: no, I am pretty sure it's correct (the output is real, I run that code). A list-comprehension is written in the same order you'd write a normal for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good, but there are a few things I've noticed that could be better:

- You should use the `with` statement when working with files. This ensures that the file will be closed properly in any case.
- I would split the input string on `','` instead of replacing the comma with a space. This way, something like `'-7,67,34,80'` will be handled correctly. (It's a bit tricky because you want to split on newlines too, though. I did it using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).)

  `int()` will ignore any whitespace before or after the number, so `int(' 50')` works just fine.
- You can write those conditions as `60 <= number <= 69`.
- Since the numbers can only fall into one of the five categories, it's clearer (and more efficient) to use `elif` instead of `if`.
- Assignments with `=` or `+=` should have spaces around them in Python. (See [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for a Python style guide.)

This is how the changes would look:

```
with open("//path to file", "r") as f:
    split = [word for line in f for word in line.split(',')]

greater70 = 0
sixties = 0
fifties = 0
forties = 0
nomarks = 0

for word in split:
    number = int(word)
    if number > 70:
        greater70 += 1
    elif 60 <= number <= 69:
        sixties += 1    
    elif 50 <= number <= 59:
        fifties += 1
    elif 40 <= number <= 49:
        forties += 1 
    elif number == -1:
        nomarks += 1           

print greater70 
print sixties
print fifties
print forties
print nomarks
```

You might also want to think about how to avoid the repetition of code when you're calculating and printing the 40s, 50s and 60s (which, by the way, are spelt `forties, fifties, sixties`).

I also noticed that 70 falls into none of the categories, is that the way it's supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

Few points i have noticed in your code, that i hope, will  help you.

1) Try changing your conditions like this: (no need to check two conditions)

```
if number > 69:
    greater70+=1
elif number > 59:
    sixtys+=1    
elif number > 49:
    fiftys+=1
elif number > 40:
    fortys+=1 
elif number == -1:
    nomarks+=1
```

2) Always take care of closing file handler, or better to use `with` statements as other expert suggested.